# Error in CDFDeploy

Tags: dynamic, warning-messages, cdf-format, cdfplayer

I'm deploying a `Manipulate` code to a CDF using `CDFDeploy`. Everything was going fine until now. All of a sudden, I'm getting the following error when running the CDF in WolframPlayer

[image]

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the error in a simpler case and my case is really long. Using Mathematica 11.3, instead of WolframPlayer, I don't get this error. I have a `DynamicModule` within the `Manipulate` code, as an output, but I've removed it and the error persisted.

Any idea what might be causing this?

**Edit:** I think I have found the source of the error, it seems to do with how I use `RegionCentroid`. Given a list `l` of polygons I get this error if I use `RegionCentroid[l]`, and don't get if I use `Map[RegionCentroid,l]`. Any idea why?

Comment: If you have `MapThread` in your code, the error message seems to suggest looking there.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. *Do* add this tag to other people's posts if the bug has been confirmed. See the tag description for more details.

Comment: Ok, I think I have found the error, it seems to do with how I use `RegionCentroid`. Given a list `l` of polygons I get this error if I use `RegionCentroid[l]`, and don't get if I use `Map[RegionCentroid,l]`. Any idea why?

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 11.3. In fact, when I ran my code in Mathematica 12.1, I do get an error regarding `RegionCentroid`. What is happening?

Comment: I have seen those errors and I know others faced it as well. Most likely it is not your fault  but I do know any good way to prevent them other than trying to refactor code till it stops appearing :-/ Regardless if I am right I do not think we can help without any piece of code.